# how dose opencv3 conflict with opencv2

Tags: c++, opencv, runtime-error

While using ROS with Orb-slam2, I met the following problem because the project invoke opencv2 and opencv3 at the same time (Exactly, orb-slam2 run with OpenCV > 2.4.3 while ROS running with opencv2)

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Invalid pointer to file storage) in cvGetFileNodeByName, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 740
```

what's more, i met this when linking:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2, needed by ../../../../lib/libORB_SLAM2.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4
```

I solved this problem by uninstalling opencv3 on my computer and use opencv2.4.8 in this whole project, but now I am confused that, 
how does opencv3 conflict with opencv2? I think that couldn't be a reason like multiple definitions because that would be detected during compiling and linking.

Hope someone could help me with this question.

Comment: It's still the same library, with mostly the same functions and classes in the same namespaces...

Comment: which didn't cause a link error, but crash at runtime?